# Can't intercept a pointcut with Spring aop

Tags: spring, javafx-2, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a application that usse JavaFX 2, and I want make sure that a specific code is called in every method of an interface:

```
public interface IControladorDialogoPrincipal extends IControladorDialogo{
    @FXML
    void abrirCaixa(ActionEvent e);

    @FXML
    void fecharCaixa(ActionEvent e);

    @FXML
    void novaPreVenda(ActionEvent evento);

    @FXML
    void mesclarPreVenda(ActionEvent evento);
}
```

This is part of the class that implements the above interface:

```
public class ControladorDialogoPrincipal extends ControladorDialogoSubmeter implements IProcessamentoListener, IControladorDialogoPrincipal {

    @FXML
    private StackPane painelPrincipal;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane painelConteudo;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane painelProgresso;
    @Autowired
    private ControladorExecucaoTarefa controladorExecucaoTarefa;
    @Autowired
    private ControladorDialogoMensagem dialogoMensagem;
    @Autowired
    private RecuperadorBeanSpring recuperadorBean;

    @Override
    protected void configurarElementos() {
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            public void handle(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        stage.setWidth(800);
        stage.setHeight(600);
        painelProgresso.toBack();
        painelProgresso.setVisible(false);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The base class for all ControladorDialogo* is this abstract class:

```
public abstract class ControladorDialogo implements IControladorDialogo {

    private URL modelo;
    protected Stage stage;
    protected String titulo = "";
    protected List<String> estilos = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public final void init() {
        try {
            stage = new Stage();
            definirTitulo(titulo);
            stage.setScene(carregarCena());
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            configurarElementos();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao tentar carregar arquivo FXML: ", e);
        }
    }

    protected final Scene carregarCena() throws IOException {
        Parent root = (Parent) SpringFXMLLoader.load(modelo.openStream(), this);
        Scene cena = new Scene(root);
        cena.getStylesheets().addAll(estilos);
        return cena;
    }

    protected void configurarElementos() {
    }

    protected void definirTitulo(String titulo) {
        if (stage != null) {
            this.titulo = titulo;
            stage.setTitle(titulo);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void abrir() {
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void fechar() {
        stage.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void setModelo(URL modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEstilos(List<String> estilos) {
        this.estilos = estilos;
    }
}
```

Here are the Spring's config of the aop and the instantiation of the ControladorDialogoPrincipal bean:

```
<bean id="controladorDialogoPrincipal" class="com.hrgi.pdv.controladores.gui.dialogos.ControladorDialogoPrincipal"
      init-method="init">
    <property name="modelo" value="classpath:gui/dialogoPrincipal.fxml"/>
    <property name="estilos" ref="estilos"/>
</bean>

<util:list id="estilos" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <value>/css/preVenda.css</value>
</util:list>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="dataSource">
        <aop:pointcut id="todosOsMetodosIControladorDialogoPrincipal" expression="execution(* com.hrgi.pdv.controladores.gui.dialogos.IControladorDialogoPrincipal.*(..))"/>
        <aop:before method="travarConexao" pointcut-ref="todosOsMetodosIControladorDialogoPrincipal"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

I want call the method "travarConexao" of this class:

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource implements Runnable {
    .
    .
    .
    private void definirConexaoAtual() {
        if (conexaoTravada && conexaoAtual.equalsIgnoreCase("secundario"))
            return;
        DataSource principal = (DataSource) fontesDeDados.get("principal");
        if (verificarConexao(principal)) {
            synchronized (conexaoAtual) {
                conexaoAtual = "principal";
            }
        } else {
            synchronized (conexaoAtual) {
                conexaoAtual = "secundario";
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean verificarConexao(DataSource principal) {
        try {
            Connection conexao = principal.getConnection();
            Statement statement = conexao.createStatement();
            return statement.executeQuery("SELECT 1") != null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void travarConexao() {
        System.out.println("\n\ncalled!!\n\n");
        definirTravaDeConexao(true);
    }

    private void definirTravaDeConexao(Boolean trava) {
        synchronized (conexaoTravada) {
            conexaoTravada = trava;
        }
        definirConexaoAtual();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Could someone explain me why this method is never called?

Comment: Can you post more on your application context or spring config file to get a fully-fledged sense of it?

Comment: Hi @DiegoJimeno, I added more information to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was poor configuration. After noticing that none of pointcuts I tryied worked (neither the simplest), I changed from pure Spring AOP to AspectJ with Spring:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:spring-configured/>

<bean class="com.hrgi.pdv.InterceptadorTravamentoConexao" scope="prototype">
    <property name="routingDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

The pointcut was moved to a annotation in a specific new class:

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class InterceptadorTravamentoConexao {

    private RoutingDataSource routingDataSource;

    @Before("execution(* com.hrgi.pdv.controladores.gui.dialogos.IControladorDialogoPrincipal.*(..))")
    public void travarConexao(){
        routingDataSource.travarConexao();
    }

    public void setRoutingDataSource(RoutingDataSource routingDataSource) {
        this.routingDataSource = routingDataSource;
    }
}
```

Added too some configuration for aspectj-compiler in maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where you can't make Spring AOP work with JavaFX 2 because JavaFX 2 components use many inner final classes and you can't inject proxies inside with CGLIB or Javassist efficiently. Actually I have not tried with AspectJ, but I believe it is the same problem.

To sum up, if you are trying to intercept a method which is inside a custom JavaFX component (extends GridPane for instance), you won't be able to do that (or maybe you are lucky, but it won't work for all methods).

If you are trying to intercept a method through a JavaFX controller (which does not extend a javafx class), be sure that Spring knows the controller through its context (check your Spring JavaFX integration). Finally if it is ok, try using CGLIB with:

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="false"/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
```

Comment: Hi @zenbeni, is there a way I can go around this limitation? Call travarConexao in all methods that need it is really bad.

Comment: @brevleq I don't know exactly what you need, did you check that your AOP configuration is correct with basic pointcuts on vanilla Spring beans? Try to define a basic HelloWorldService in Spring and add a pointcut on one method, see what happens then. If it does not work then javafx is not the problem, probably a dependency / configuration problem (with or without cglib).